# VKVideoplayer usage in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, video-streaming

I am trying to implement VKVideoplayer in Swift. I have used it as pod and imported the library in bridge class.

Now I am using the below code to start the video player, I am getting the video player in my view however, video stream is not happening

```
    var player:VKVideoPlayer = VKVideoPlayer()
    player.view.frame = self.view.bounds
    player.delegate =  self
    self.view.addSubview(player.view)
    var videotrack:VKVideoPlayerTrack = VKVideoPlayerTrack()
    videotrack.streamURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/videos/AA3C120C521177175800441692160_38f2cbd1ffb.1.5.13763579289575020226.mp4")
    videotrack.hasNext = true
    player.loadVideoWithTrack(video track)
```

The activity indicator is loading without the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@IBAction func play() {
    let videoURLString = "http://......."
    let videoVC = VKVideoPlayerViewController()
    presentViewController(videoVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    videoVC.playVideoWithStreamURL(NSURL(string: videoURLString))
}
```

I don't know why it does not work if I use segue to switch view controller, so I just put it by code